# Multiple route with the same pattern url

Tags: java, spring

I m actually creating a simple application and I need to have routing pattern identical in multiple case :

```
/*
* Returns a list of all the root directories accepting query string on name
*/
@RequestMapping(value = "/directories", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<DirectoryEntity> find() {
    return directoryService.findAll();
}


/*
* Returns a list of all the root directories accepting query string on name
* @param name Name of the ressources to search. Query string at format : *name*
*/
@RequestMapping(value = "/directories", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<DirectoryEntity> findByCriteria(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name) {
    return directoryService.findByName(name);
}
```

In fact, I dont want to manage criteria request in the same function as findAll one. Is there anyway to handle this case without be forced to manage everything inside the same function ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the second method @RequestMapping annotation adding params:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/directories", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "name")
public List<DirectoryEntity> findByCriteria(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name) {
    return directoryService.findByName(name);
}
```

See also the [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but assuming the decision as to which method to call is based on request parameters (it must be since they're both the same URL and HTTP method), then something like this might help:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, params={"name"})
public @ResponseBody List<DirectoryEntity> findByCriteria(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

The inclusion of the `params` attribute in the `@RequestMapping` annotation removes the ambiguity in which method to call.

I've also added `@ResponseBody` to the return type, just in case you want Spring to return the list in the HTTP response.

Comment: an alternative to adding `@ResponseBody` for each method could be to use `@RestController` annotation on the class, which would provide `@ResponseBody` for each method automatically